# Flask error when trying to import a model

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a user through terminal, but I got this message:

(I've already take a look on SQLAlchemy's documentation. I had no problems creating the User class and starting the db at the same file, but I'm not finding where is my problem when I work with different files)

```
>>> test = User('a', 'b', 'c')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

My directory tree:

```
+-- __init__.py
+-- models
|   +-- tables.py
```

My **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

manager = Manager(app)

from app.models import tables
from app.controllers import default
```

My tables.py (The file where I creted the User model):

```
from app import db
from flask_login import UserMixin


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    def __init__(self, name, username, password):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
from tables import User
# or models.tables, or app.models.tables, if not in same directory
test = User('a', 'b', 'c')
```

and you should have an `__init__.py` file in `models` directory.  What directory are you running this from?

Comment: Thank you GAEfan! I just had to import the model correctly, once I imported User from "app.models.tables" it worked as I expect.